# Selenium Python don't work in chrome using options.add_argument("--headless")

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hy guys,

I'm trying to run this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\\Users\\gabriel.lucena\\Documents\\Python Scripts")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver.get("xpage")
```

and they work if this argument options.add_argument("--headless") is down

Comment: run this code *

Answer (score 0):

Where is your driver initialization. you need to pass chrome options while initialize the driver like.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\Users\gabriel.lucena\Documents\Python Scripts")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

---

Now if you just run this code to check whether headless options works.

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
print(driver.title)
```